# React Native - How to make portion of TouchableOpacity not pressable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity

I have a `Card` component that displays a listing on the app's dashboard page. The whole card is wrapped in a `TouchableOpacity`. I want the entire card to be Pressable, which links to the listings page.

However, I want the bottom right corner of it to not be pressable, since it contains a `View` that has 2 icons on it (a Like button and a Message button). Each of these icons has their own `onPress()` that needs to happen.

Right now, if you try to click on the bottom right icons, it just triggers the whole `TouchableOpacity`

Here is the `return` statement for `Card`:

```
return (
<Container>
  <Cover style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
    <Image
      source={{
        width: 80,
        height: 90,
        url: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
      }}
    />
  </Cover>
  <Content>
    <Title>{props.name}</Title>
    <PriceCaption>{"$" + props.price}</PriceCaption>
    <View
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        height: 35,
        width: 100,
        top: 45,
        right: 0,
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "Flex-end",
      }}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          ...styles.ButtonBackground,
          backgroundColor: null,
          left: 70,
        }}
        onPress={() => {
          launchChat();
        }}
        title={"message"}
      >
        <AntDesign name="mail" size={26} color={colours.purple} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          ...styles.ButtonBackground,
          backgroundColor: null,
          marginLeft: 0,
          left: 10,
        }}
        onPress={() => {
          launchChat();
        }}
        title={"message"}
      >
        <AntDesign name="heart" size={26} color={colours.purple} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </Content>
</Container>);
```

Is there a property, or way I can exclude a nested `View` from a `TouchableOpacity`?

**Note:** If you click on the `Icons`, they still trigger their respective `onPress()`, however, the entire Card still fades out, and the animation is the same as if you clicked elsewhere on the card (so user gets poor feedback on where they clicked).

Comment: You could absolute-position that view instead of nesting it

Answer (score 2):

I have an understanding problem in your question, but I believe that wrapping with TouchableWithoutFeedback might be a solution or pointerEvents={"none"} property. If you do a little research on the keyword TouchableWithoutFeedback component from react-native, I think you will get the result you want

Answer (score 0):

I frequently place some TouchableOpacity in other TouchableOpacities. When you press on inner TO, the inner will be pressed not the parent. So you shouldn't think about making some area of parent unpressable.

[image]I just test my sample code to be sure. As I said earlier, it should work. I have no idea what causes this problem in your case.

Comment: right now, that is how i have it set up, nested TouchableOpacity. However, when clicking in the area of the inner one, it still activates the outer as well (The outer also fades out)

Answer (score 0):

This may not help everybody, but here was my issue and what I did to fix it.

Previous code (with the issue):

```
<Pressable onPress={() => doSomething()}>
  <View /> // the Pressable's onPress would trigger when this View is pressed
</Pressable>
```

The code with the fix:

```
<Pressable onPress={() => doSomething()}>
  <Pressable /> // This no longer calls doSomething when pressed.
</Pressable>
```